# Strange Crash issue + iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, crash-reports

This crash log is from a customer using my iPad app. There are only two lines in the crash log which point to my app - Thread 0 line 19 & 20.

The app works fine for most of the users but not for few others. The app is used few hundred times every day, yet I only get very few of these reports.

I am using third party libraries like ASIHttpRequest, GData, Reachability if that might help.

Here is the crash log:

```
Date/Time:       2011-04-17 21:29:44.848 +0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32981a1c 0x32970000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b83b4 0x30585000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b0bf8 0x30585000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35e1ea64 0x35dda000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3670e06c 0x36708000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35e1ce36 0x35dda000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35e1ce8a 0x35dda000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35e1cf5a 0x35dda000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3670cc84 0x36708000 + 19588
9   Foundation                      0x35330924 0x352a1000 + 588068
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35990a72 0x3591b000 + 481906
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35992758 0x3591b000 + 489304
12  CoreFoundation                  0x359934e4 0x3591b000 + 492772
13  CoreFoundation                  0x35923ebc 0x3591b000 + 36540
14  CoreFoundation                  0x35923dc4 0x3591b000 + 36292
15  GraphicsServices                0x31f80418 0x31f7c000 + 17432
16  GraphicsServices                0x31f804c4 0x31f7c000 + 17604
17  UIKit                           0x320d4d62 0x320a6000 + 191842
18  UIKit                           0x320d2800 0x320a6000 + 182272
19  MyApp                           0x00002e58 main (main.m:14)
20  MyApp                           0x00002e0c start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32982fbc 0x32970000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b08094 0x34b02000 + 24724
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b0904a 0x34b02000 + 28746
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b0860a 0x34b02000 + 26122
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b958a 0x30585000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b9bbc 0x30585000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3297fc00 0x32970000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3297f758 0x32970000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x359912b8 0x3591b000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35993562 0x3591b000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35923ebc 0x3591b000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35923dc4 0x3591b000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x307d9292 0x307d3000 + 25234
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b830a 0x30585000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b9bb4 0x30585000 + 215988

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3297fc00 0x32970000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3297f758 0x32970000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x359912b8 0x3591b000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35993562 0x3591b000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35923ebc 0x3591b000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35923dc4 0x3591b000 + 36292
6   Foundation                      0x352cb7f6 0x352a1000 + 174070
7   Foundation                      0x352be382 0x352a1000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x353305c6 0x352a1000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b830a 0x30585000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b9bb4 0x30585000 + 215988

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32981c60 0x32970000 + 72800
1   CoreFoundation                  0x359968f2 0x3591b000 + 506098
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b830a 0x30585000 + 209674
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b9bb4 0x30585000 + 215988

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x329823ec 0x32970000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b96d8 0x30585000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x305b9bbc 0x30585000 + 215996

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0x3e2ca48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0464042c      r7: 0x2fdfe98c
r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x323aabc4     r11: 0x3ea4f818
ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe980      lr: 0x305b83bb      pc: 0x32981a1c
cpsr: 0x000f0010"
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to symbolicate your crash log

Comment: This is a symbolicated crash log. It is just that it is not having any call to the code written by me.

Comment: I've got the exact same stack trace / issue - and it happened to an Apple reviewer, but no-one else, so the app has been rejected. Xcode4 symbolication is still broken (c.f. other stackoverflow answers), but a partial symbolication gives no obvious info on what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SIGABRT most likely means an assertion failure somewhere, so have a look to see if any might be fired in edge cases.